# React Native: set headers with the Linking api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How can I setRequestHeader in React Native? Like the following:

```
var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
client.open("GET", "http://www.example.com/api");
client.setRequestHeader("authorization", "Bearer Access_Token");
client.send();
```

I can't find any info in the Linking api doc. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to make request with headers to website, you need http(s) request, not linking between 2 apps.

As mentioned in other answer, linking api does not have headers. While fetching remote address with http(s) do have headers

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html

```
fetch('https://mywebsite.com/endpoint/', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    firstParam: 'yourValue',
    secondParam: 'yourOtherValue',
  })
})
```

Comment: But how do you then transfer the return result into the browser?

Comment: @deworde check included link, it has samples with promise chain and `await`'

Comment: Sorry, wasn't clear. That explains how to get access to the result, but then forwarding that result into Safari or Chrome is what I'm struggling with, which openURL gives you automatically.

Comment: This is off-topic for this question, please create new question

Comment: [Done](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51062655/14250), but this was a related question and I wanted to see if it covered both parts.

Answer (score 1):

The Linking API is for linking between apps on the device. There is no notion of headers when linking between apps. Use query parameters in the URL instead.