# React Native: How can I set HTTP headers when opening a link as if with Linking.openURL

Tags: react-native

Within a React-Native app (running on iOS), I am trying to open a specific webpage on a content store within the phone's default browser.

`Linking.openUrl` only allows you to supply a url, and I need to supply a jwt token as part of the "Authorization" header for my request to succeed (otherwise I get a login screen).

I can do successful "fetch(...)" requests within the react-native app setting the headers appropriately, but [there doesn't appear to be an app-to-app way to set the headers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41473270/14250).

Is this unsupported, and is there a package to support this?

Comment: Update: We got the user to change their behaviour so we could use just url parameters